Date Difference - Power BI
Based on the below table I want to calculate the difference (in days) between the current date and the previous date this Category appears in the past.

Notes

In case there is no previous appearance i do not to show anything.
Table in not sorted.

Up to now
I manage to add index in each row ordered by date.
Any ideas how to proceed?

You could try
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Category"}, {{"data", each 
    let a=Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.Sort(_,{{"Date", Order.Ascending}}), "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type)
    in Table.AddColumn(a,"Output", each try Duration.Days([Date] - a[Date]{[Index]-1}) otherwise null)
, type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Date", "Output"}, {"Date", "Output"})
in  #"Expanded data"



Appreciate you help.

you can create a calculated column as bellow-
output = 

var this_row_category = your_table_name[category]
var this_row_date = your_table_name[date]

var previous_date_this_category =
calculate(
    max(your_table_name[date]),
    filter(
        all(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[category] = this_row_category
            && your_table_name[date] < this_row_date
    )

)

return
if(
    NOT ISBLANK(previous_date_this_category), 
    DATEDIFF(previous_date_this_category,this_row_date,DAY)
)

Here is the result-


I created 3 DAX measures (MAXDate and PrevDate can be variables in final measure):
// One that calculates max date for each category:
MAXDate =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( 'Table'[Date] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[Category] )
)

// One that calculates previous date:
PrevDate = 
VAR MaxDate =
    MAX ( 'Table'[Date] )
VAR MaxPrevDate =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Table'[Date] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Table' ),
            'Table'[Date] < MaxDate
                && 'Table'[Category] = MAX ( 'Table'[Category] )
        )
    )
RETURN
    MaxPrevDate

// One that calculates difference of days between the two measures above:
DateDiff =
IF ( [PrevDate] <> BLANK (), DATEDIFF ( [PrevDate], [MAXDate], DAY ) )

The result:

